# php\r nu such file or directory when trying to run phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant

I'm trying to run phpunit in my vagrant server in virtualbox(Ubuntu) for a school project, but I'm unable to.

I'm certain that my that phpunit is located in vendor/bin/phpunit and my test project is also in the right directory and everything is spelled correctly so I don't understand why I get this error.

I try to do:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit test/model/PDOGameModelTest.php
```

the error that I get is:

> usr/bin/env: 'php\r': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Your file uses DOS file ending (CR+LF) and Ubuntu uses Unix one (LF). You have to convert your file with the command `dos2unix` :

Install it with :

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Convert it with :

```
dos2unix test/model/PDOGameModelTest.php
```

Then :

```
vendor/bin/phpunit test/model/PDOGameModelTest.php
```

**Edit** : Another solution

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' test/model/PDOGameModelTest.php > test/model/PDOGameModelTest_converted.php
```

Comment: Can you try : `awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' test/model/PDOGameModelTest.php > test/model/PDOGameModelTest_converted.php ` **and then** `vendor/bin/phpunit test/model/PDOGameModelTest_converted.php` ?

Comment: I'm glad I helped ! I've edit my answer. As the problem is solved, you can now mark the question as `resolved`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but in my case it was a file

```
\vendor\bin\phpunit
```

it used DOS file ending (CR+LF) and Ubuntu uses Unix one (LF).

So I changed this file with NetBeans and the issue was fixed.

> To change End Of File (EOF) in NetBeans just right click on the "file ending name" on a main window status bar.